# Multiple range product in Python

Tags: python, range, generator, permutation

Is there a better way to do this:

```
perms = product(range(1,7),range(1,7),range(1,7))
```

so that I can choose how many ranges I use?
I want it to be equivalent to this, but scalable.

```
def dice(num)
    if num == 1:
        perms = ((i,) for i in range(1,7))
    elif num == 2:
        perms = product(range(1,7),range(1,7))
    elif num == 3:
        perms = product(range(1,7),range(1,7),range(1,7))
    #... and so on
```

but I know there has to be a better way.
I'm using it for counting dice outcomes.
The actual code

```
def dice(selection= lambda d: d[2]):   
    perms = itertools.product(range(1,7),range(1,7),range(1,7))      
    return collections.Counter(((selection(sorted(i)) for i in perms)))
```

where I can call it with a variety of selectors, like `sum(d[0:2])` for the sum of the lowest 2 dice or `d[1]` to get the middle dice.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes.  Use the `repeat` keyword argument:

```
perms = product(range(1, 7), repeat=3)
```

See the [docs](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product) for more.

Comment: Oh, how did I miss that?  I was even on that doc page.  *facepalm*
Thank You

Comment: Slightly related: Is there any difference if you use `irange`? I'm in the case where my ranges in my `product` are large.

Comment: @Annan: How large? `itertools.product` _does_ immediately convert each of its arguments into a list internally, so even in Python 3 where `range` is lazy, you can expect `perms = itertools.product(range(10**9))` to take a lot of time and memory even before you start to iterate over `perms`. OTOH, `itertools.product(range(100), repeat=100)` should be fine, since it's only generating 100 lists of length 100 up front. (I'm not familiar with `irange`, but I guess you're referring to something like Python 3's `range`.)

Comment: Yes, I did mean a lazy range. I got slightly confused between (i/x/)range py(2/3). Knowing that product needs to convert to list answers my question, thanks. I was consider the implications of replacing nested loops with loop over product.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
perms = itertools.product(*([xrange(1,7)]*num))
```

should work for you.